# Как задать ключ для JSON строки в Arduino в цикле

Tags: json, arduino

Использую библиотеку ArduinoJson.h

Вот такой код:

```
...

char json2[] =
      "{\"0\":1,\"1\":2,\"2\":4,\"3\":6,\"4\":16,\"5\":32,\"6\":64,\"7\":77}";

DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json2);

int pin_status;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

   pin_status = doc[ i ];   //<-----  как тут правильно скормить ключ?

   Serial.println(pin_status);
}

//А так работает:
pin_status = doc["0"];
Serial.println(pin_status);
pin_status = doc["1"];
Serial.println(pin_status);
pin_status = doc["7"];
Serial.println(pin_status);

...
```

Тут на выходе всегда получаются нули
**pin_status = doc[ i ];**

А если так
**pin_status = doc["7"];**
то все ок

Не пойму, как правильно обозначить ключ для doc в цикле. 
Пробовал так doc[char(i)] и так doc["\""+String(i)+"\""]

Answer (score 0):

PS пока писал вопрос, сам понял уже, где ступил =) Должно быть так

```
pin_status = doc[String(i)];
```

Оставлю это здесь, если можно. Может кому понадобится.